# Search multiple criteria mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am getting the following error please help

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\hosting\10102937\html\search.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\hosting\10102937\html\search.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\hosting\10102937\html\search.php on line 25

this is my PHP code

```
include("connection.php");

$type = $_POST['type'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$bedrooms = $_POST['bedrooms'];
$min = $_POST['price'];
$max = $_POST['price'];
//$sql ="SELECT * FROM subscribers2 WHERE type  = '%$type%' AND address = '%$address%' AND bedrooms = '%$bedrooms%' AND min as '%$min%' AND max as '%$max%' ";


$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscribers2 WHERE type  = '%$type%' AND address = '%$address%' AND bedrooms = '%$bedrooms%' AND min as '%$price%' AND max as '%$price%' "); 



$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscribers2 WHERE type  LIKE '%$type%' AND address LIKE '%$address%' AND bedrooms LIKE '%$bedrooms%' AND min as '%$price%' AND max as '%$price%' "); 
$number=mysql_num_rows($query); 
?>
```

Comment: It looks like your query `$sql` when you have the query string commented out.

Comment: Note that this search is wide open for sql injection! Use PDO!

Comment: @peterpan Youre right, take away the two // and you will be fine. Peterpan you should add this as your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query `$sql` when you have the query string commented out.

But that is only 1 of 3 mysql errors.

You will find out the error using `mysql_error` [as documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php).

You should also look into SQL Injection, your parameters are being passed directly through POST to database level, which leaves your server's database wide open.

Comment: many thanks for your response, I am new to php and myslq, I took off the comment on $sql as you pointed, could you give me a closer example please

Comment: You will need to tell me what is being printed out by mysql_error first

Comment: this is what i get when perform search?Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\hosting\10102937\html\search.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\hosting\10102937\html\search.php on line 23

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\hosting\10102937\html\search.php on line 25

Comment: Write your queries using this style to find out why it is failing: https://gist.github.com/4186050.